# Expression Language in java

Tags: java

I have files in my directory like

```
/home/jay/120123.txt
/home/jay/121343.txt
/home/jay/122123.txt
```

The key here is first three digit of the file names is unique. How do i write expression language in java (never written EL in java) which will be same as unix command "ls 120*" = "120123.txt"

So something like String getFile(String uniqueId) this method will for instance be called as

```
String file = getFile("120") and the file should be 120123.txt
```

I need the logic for getFile() method

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Neither, he's asking how to glob a filesystem.

Comment: Can Scala be consider EL in Java? `new java.io.File("/home/jay").listFiles filter {_.getName.startsWith("120")}`

Comment: If you're on Java 7, you can use this `Files.newDirectoryStream()` overload: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path, java.lang.String)

Comment: How do you do the Glob operation with Files.newDirectoryStream()?

Comment: @millimoose I can understand there are 2 questions: how to write the EL and the logic for the method. The answers provided point to the second, but none to the first.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Raimeus' seems to tackle both.

Comment: @millimoose this is [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html). Otherwise, I'm wrong or OP has confused the terms.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes he has, that's what I'm trying to say since the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the File.listFiles(FilenameFilter).

Maybe in something like that:

```
public File[] getFiles(File folder, String prefix){
    return folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
            return name.startsWith(prefix);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think the crux of the OP's question isn't just how to list files, but also how to do shell-style filename matching, which `startsWith()` isn't.

Comment: Well, his question is quite confusing, because he mentions globs in the text, but he doesn't pass anything that looks like a glob to his hypothetical getFile(String) function. In the end, An answer can only be as good as the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

For **Java 6**

You may find the `WildcardFileFilter` in [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io) useful for this:

```
File dir = new File(".");
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("120*.txt");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(files[i].getName());
}
```

For **Java 7**

[Files.newDirectoryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream%28java.nio.file.Path%29) offers this functionality:

```
Path dir = Paths.get(".");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "120*.txt")) {
    for (Path entry : stream) {
        System.out.println(entry.getFileName());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed the WildCard solution; thats what i wanted. But i need small change. It is printing entire file path and name. i just want file name like 120123.txt and not /home/jay120123.txt

Comment: Reimus - i fail to understand one thing. I don't have apache commons jar (commons-io) in my classpath. But then how is it working w/o runtime error .. is it included somehow in java6?

Comment: No needs separate jar AFAIK. You should check your imports to see if it is [this one](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/WildcardFileFilter.html). If so, it must be somewhere on your classpath. If not, could be a custom implementation, but unlikely.

Comment: Yes, i have that in my import but don't i need that jar to be in my classpath?

Comment: I dont have commons-io-1.3.2.jar in my classpath. thats what is baffling me.